# CMD add every variable generated to a list

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, command-line-arguments, command-prompt

I know I can write an echo > C:/Folder/name.txt
But I have a generator to make 2 number for Cord and can't figure out a quick way to make a one line echo > with all the points
for shortness I'll simplify my code because the current code is not the issue

```
Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set R=1
set Number=1
:Loop
if %R% EQU 1 (set /p Max=How many Max Points? ) Else(
echo.)
set /p PX%number%=What is PointX%number%? 
set /p PY%number%=What is PointY%number%? 
if %Number% GEQ %Max% (goto :fin) Else(
set /a Number=%Number%+1 & set R=2 & Goto :loop)
```

**This Is what Im trying to Optimize**

```
:fin
echo (%PX1%,%PY1%),(%PX2%,%PY2%),(%PX3%,%PY3%) ... Ect >C:Folder/File.txt
```

Is there any way to make all the generated numbers on **1** line

Comment: Did you try creating a variable called LINE and just keep adding to it? `set "line=%line%(PX%number%,PY%number%),"`

Comment: `set "list="` & `for /L %%i in (1,1,%Max%) do set "list=!list!(!PX%%i!,!PY%%i!),"` & `echo %list:~0,-1%>C:Folder/File.txt`

Comment: @Aacini Sorry I don't understand **For** really Squashman put it in a more simple answer

Comment: @Aacini, I was thinking of doing the same thing but I must have read his mind and thought it might look too complicated so I just added the one line.

Comment: Squashman's code show a _literal string_ like this one: `(PX1,PY1),(PX2,PY2),...`. My method show _the values_ of the points, that I assumed is what you want...

Comment: @aacini Would this work - - - set line=%line%(!PX%number%!,!PY%number%!),

Comment: Yes. I posted this mod below...

Answer (score 1):

**Credit to Squashman for the Answer - Thank you!**

*Correct Code:*

```
Echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set R=1
set Number=1
set Line=Test
:Loop
if %R% EQU 1 (set /p Max=How many Max Points? ) Else (
echo.)
set /p PX%number%=What is PointX%number%? 
set /p PY%number%=What is PointY%number%? 
set line=%line%(!PX%number%!,!PY%number%!),
if %Number% GEQ %Max% (goto :fin) Else (
set /a Number=%Number%+1 & set R=2 & Goto :loop)
:fin
echo %Line:~0,-1% >C:Folder/File.txt
```

**Credit to Squashman for the Answer - Thank you!**

Comment: You need to modify this line `set line=%line%(PX%number%,PY%number%),` by this one: `set line=%line%(!PX%number%!,!PY%number%!),` in order to show _the values_ of the points, and show just `echo %Line:~0,-1% ...` to remove the last comma

Answer (score 0):

The logic is so much simpler if you get the max point count before the loop. And the FOR /L loop can auto increment your counter and eliminate the need for GOTO.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p "cnt=How many points? "
set "ln="
for /l %%N in (1 1 %cnt%) do (
  echo(
  set /p "PX%%N=What is PointX%%N? "
  set /p "PY%%N=What is PointY%%N? "
  set "ln=!ln!(!PX%%N!,!PY%%N!),"
)
echo(
echo !ln:~0,-1!
```